# Saving and retrieving an image from parse in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I have a class called `ProfilePage` and in that I am selecting an image to display as the profile picture. I have successfully opened an image using an ImagePickerController. However, I am having trouble uploading this image to my Parse.com dashboard into my 'Users' class.

I'm trying to upload the image from the UIImagePicker  to Parse.com.  I've followed a few tutorials and looked at the documentation for uploading files but they all add it to a new 'Class' in parse. I want to be able to upload into my 'Users' class where i have a field called 'Profile Picture'

```
class ProfilePage: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var editProfilePicture: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTag: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Bio: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveProfileChanges: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameTag.text = ((PFUser.current()?.username)!)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapSaveProfileChanges(_ sender: Any) {
        PFUser.current()?.username = "Kane"

        do {
            try PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("unable to save new username")
                }
                else {
                    print("new username saved")
                    self.viewDidLoad()
                }
            })
        } catch  {
            print("unable to save new username")
        }

    @IBAction func didTapBackButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToHomePage", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapChooseImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self


        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                print("There no is no camera available")
            }
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        profilePicture.image = image
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: We are not mind readers. Please update your question (do not post comments) with details about your issue. You can't just post code with no explanation of what issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, I use this code to upload my images to my bank

```
    let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoProfile.image!,0.00001)

    var myPFObj = PFObject(className:"YouClass")

    let myFile = PFFile(name: "ProfilePic", data: profileImageData!)    
    myPFObj.setObject(myFile!, forKey: "profile_picture")

    myPFObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
      if (success) {

      } else {

      }
    }
```

I hope to help with something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly its important to look at the migration docs about moving from parse.com because it is soon to close down.

http://parse.com/migration

Now to your question. Here is a example in swift 3 for a current logged in user.

```
@IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!


// ImagePicker delegate
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        profilePicture.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func updateProfileImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
                let userToUpdate = PFUser.current()!


                    // Save Avatar
                    if profilePicture.image != nil {
                        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(avatarImg.image!, 0.5)
                        let imageFile = PFFile(name:"avatar.jpg", data:imageData!)
                        userToUpdate["profilePicture"] = imageFile
                    }

                    // Saving block
                    userToUpdate.saveInBackground(block: { (succ, error) in
                        if error == nil {

                            print("Your Profile has been updated!")
                        } else {

                            print("Failed")

                    }})


    }
```